# Page number is not printed on last page (before the appendices)

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I have a thesis document where I use the following page numbering

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}

\lhead{}
\rhead{}
\chead{Very title\\ Very myself}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\onehalfspace

\newpage
{\setstretch{1.5}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\section{Introduction} 

...

\clearpage
\section{Conclusions and future work}

} % setstretch

\end{document}
```

On very last page of conclusions chapter the page number is not being printed. I have few appendices after that chapter and I do not need the page numbers there either but I need the page numbers up to the last page of conclusions chapter.

What is wrong? What can I add to force printing the page number on a page?

**EDIT**

I added the code with described problem - there's no page number on last page (with conclusions chapter).

Comment: Please turn your code snippet into a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Well, if the page numbering does not work on the last page of Conclusions, you should include that in your MWE as well. The Introduction it this case is not sufficient.

Comment: Also, where does the `{` before `\setstretch` ends?

Comment: I have added the code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\pagestyle` applies the page style locally, so you ought to put it *before* the group for `\setstretch`, or maybe better invoke `\clearpage` just before the end of the group.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}

\lhead{}
\rhead{}
\chead{Very title\\ Very myself}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\onehalfspace

\newpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
{\setstretch{1.5}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\section{Introduction} 

...

\clearpage
\section{Conclusions and future work}

} % setstretch

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Patryk You are welcome. And for the next time, please notice how necessary a MWE is: without your code, the solution would be impossible to guess, with your code, the solution took less than a minute ;)